# Ruby On Rails -- Check boxs , Dropdowns , Radio buttons

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, types

I want to know how to set the datatype for dropdowns , checkboxes , radio buttons .. I'm using mysql as backend

thanks for advance help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ruby all things like numbers, strings are objects. We don't need to specify any datatype to variables.

example-

```
<%= f.radio_button(:A_Impact_Value,1) %>
```

so here A_Impact_Value datatype can be integer,boolean .